# Guice injector inside a thread

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a doubt using Guice. I have a class that I call `Main` that is constructor injected using  Guice and a method that every time that is called creates an o thread object of class `AppThread`. `AppThread` is a private class inside `Main`. The problem is that inside the execution of the thread I want to create an object of class `ClassX`. This object is constructor injected using Guice. I don't know what's the best form to inject the objects of `ClassX`. My first solution is inject the `Injector` inside `Main` and inside the thread use the injector to inject the objects of class `ClassX`.

Does exists a cleaner approach to inject the dependences inside the thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having your own subclass of `Thread` (which is discouraged anyway) you should write your "thread code" as a regular object that implements `Runnable`.  Your `Main` class should inject this class (or you can actually inject a `Provider<MyRunnable>` if you need to instantiate an unknown number of them).  Then your `Main` class can create a `new Thread(myRunnable)` and it should all fit together nicely.

```
public class MyMainClass {
    @Inject
    MyMainClass(Provider<MyRunnable> runnableProvider) { ... }

    public void spawnThread() {
        new Thread(runnableProvider.get()).start();
    }
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Inject
    MyRunnable(ClassX myX) { ... }
    public void run() {
        ... do work ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, but the question was about creating instances of `ClassA` inside the `Runnable`. Injecting the `Injector` into the `Runnable` instance or using a better method.

Comment: Yes, using providers is better than inject the Injector. Thanks

Comment: @Andreas_D: you should try to avoid injecting the `Injector` if you can.  Yes, there are times you have to, but usually you can just inject a `Provider<T>` instead and hand it off.  The same methodology I use here applies in a number of cases.

Comment: I think I misread your comment, @Andreas_D.  As for injecting ClassA into the runnable, you can simply put it in your constructor `@Inject MyRunnable(ClassA injectedClassA) { ... }`.